# Why does $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x-3}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ and not $\frac{-1}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I can't figure out why $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x-3}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ and not $\frac{-1}{2}$.

Let me show you my work.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x-3}{2}$$

$$=\frac{0(x-3)-2(1)}{2^2}$$

$$=\frac{0-2}{4}=\frac{-2}{4}=\frac{-1}{2}$$

But the online calculator I used does it this way.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x-3}{2}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(x-3)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}(1-0)=\frac{1}{2}-0 = \frac{1}{2}$$

I can't tell what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: $u'v-v'u$ on top, not $uv'-u'v$.

Comment: Remembering small examples like this can be helpful for remembering these rules correctly.  You should be able to graph this function, and you should be able to see from the graph or see intuitively in other ways that the slope should be positive, not negative.  If you ever forget what order they should be in, pull this example from the back of your mind and double check that the formula gives the correct answer for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your quotient rule reversed for the numerator. So you ended up with the negative of the answer. The rule is $$\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)' =\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2},$$
but if you look closely, you'll see you did $\color{red}{uv'-u'v}$ in the numerator instead.

Comment: Whoops, I see it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There's a *mnemonic* to help you remember the quotient rule:   "low d(high) minus high d(low), down below the square must go".

Alternatively,  you could note that you have $\dfrac12x-\dfrac 32$, so that the derivative is indeed $\dfrac 12$.

Comment: OHHHH THE *MNEMONIC ALTERNATIVE*. `<3`

Comment: @manooooh takes me back.  One of my tutees taught me, years ago.

Comment: I had learned "low d(high) minus high d(low)" but hadn't ever heard the second half which solidifies which order it should be with the rhyme.  Very useful, I'll use that in the future.

Comment: @JMoravitz right:  if you get it backwards it doesn't rhyme.  Great!